# Block country for special address or URL with htaccess and GeoIP

Tags: .htaccess, block, access-denied, geoip, restrict

I want restrict access one or more specific country IPs for URL or address such as "/cart.php?a=checkout".
How can do this with htaccess and Geo-IP mod ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example you can use this code:

```
<FilesMatch "^(cart\.php|viewinvoice\.php)$">

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE DE BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE IN BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RU BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE UA BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE EC BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE VN BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CN BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE AM BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE LV BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE TR BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE FR BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SA BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE PL BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE NL BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE SG BlockCountry

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=BlockCountry
```

Comment: what if you have other stuff going on in the `.htaccess` file?  what if you need to assign different files with different country access in the same folder....how would you handle this?